# Extracting date from day of the year and put it in a separate column

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have file `MOD17A1.A2002047.h20v09.058.2007117021342.hdf` that is stored in my database. I have a column with the file names like that (the name of column is `_filename_`). `2002047` in the filename means day 47 of the year 2002. I have to extract the date in the date format like `2002-02-16` into a separate column for each file name.

I came up with this solution:

```
with S as (
   select (select substring(filename from 10 for 4) || (select hiph)
          || (select substring(filename from 14 for 3))) as D
  ,mytable.rid as s_rid from mytable)
update mytable
set date_column = (select (to_date(d , 'IYYY-IDDD')')::date)
from S
where id=s_id
```

The only problem with this solution is that I need a column `_hiph_` which all the values are `'-'`. Is there a way that I run this command in postgresql without this `_hiph_` column? Or any alternative solution?

Comment: Do you want the ISO day of year (which starts with the Monday of the first ISO week) or the plain day of the year? With ISO, your example would be `2002-02-15`, *not* `2002-02-16`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After untangling this .. monster I was able to simplify it .. a bit ..

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    date_column = to_date(substr(filename, 10, 7), 'IYYYIDDD');
```

Seriously.

This updates *all* rows in the table.

`hiph` - obviously a hyphen (`-`) is not needed. Just adapt your pattern in `to_date()`.

As commented, this produces the date '2002-02-15' for your example according to ISO format.
If the count of days starts with *Jan. 1st* use the pattern `'YYYYDDD'` instead.
[More about that in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)

Comment: Thank you. I have to use `'YYYYDDD'`. this gives me the required result.